# Why ProxySettings doesn't work in EmbeddedWB ? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, proxy

This is my code :

```
EmbeddedWB1.ProxySettings.Address:='119.112.222.146';
EmbeddedWB1.ProxySettings.Port:=9415;
EmbeddedWB1.ProxySettings.AutoLoadProxy:=true;
EmbeddedWB1.RefreshProxy;
EmbeddedWB1.Navigate('www.whatismyipaddress.com');
```

But when i navigated the site , my ip address did NOT change ! whereas , when i set that proxy settings(119.112.222.146:9415) for IE manually , it's work gracefully !!

What's wrong ?

Comment: Can you try with "EmbeddedWB1.ProxySettings.AutoLoadProxy:=false;"?